# Does SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST give results for the node, or the cluster?

Tags: mysql, rds

I have a clustered mysql environment in AWS with a master and 7 slaves.  I connected to the master and I ran `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`.  I was wondering if that command gives me connection information for all the cluster (ie: Will it tell me who's connecting to the slaves, too?), or will it only tell me who's connected to the master?

Comment: Just the current node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SHOW PROCESSLIST` (and the `FULL` variety) will only show the running queries on the server you execute that query on, be it master or slave. I know of no way to do what you're asking in a native MySQL fashion - the closest I could find is [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-slave-hosts.html), which when run from the master, shows all servers that are or have been connected as a slave (though not their queries).

If your scripting is good (and assuming network latency isn't too big a problem) then you might be able to write something in your favorite language that remotely runs that command on all master/slave servers and outputs it in a pretty format - could be a fun project!